# German and french keyboard

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, language-support

I never used windows but had to while changing the laptop. I was immediatelly able to change keyboard settings to US international with all the french and german accents.

I now hope for an equally intuitive setting when upgrading to 18.4 but can not solve the problem. The keyboard is set to US international with all dead keys but when pressing the combinations, I get no accents.

Thank you for support and best from Berlin, Ismael

Comment: It ought to be as simple as you describe, i.e. enabling the _English (US, intl., with dead keys)_ keyboard layout. With that layout you should be able to press `'` followed by `a` to get `á`. Please edit your question and add details about which keys you press. That would make it easier to give you the hints you need to get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues and almost identical setup. Switching from MS Windows world to Linux, I installed Ubuntu Desktop 18.04.40 LTS a few days ago. 
Language is set to 'English (United States)'. Keyboard is set to 'English US'. My physical keyboard is a Logitech 'US international keyboard'.

I couldn't use my [Alt] key with numeric code anymoe and was stuck until I found the Tweaks app. Tweaks should help you. I set the the Compose key to 'Left Control'. That did it. German Umlaute and Spanish special characters can be typed now.

Hope that helps.